# implementation of User class by using object

Tags: php

i am new to php and i want to achieve the following. i have search on internet but i didnt find any help.

```
$user = new User();
$user->setFirstName('John')->setLastName('Doe')->setEmail('john.doe@example.com');
echo $user;
```

and i want the output like the following

```
   "John Doe <john.doe@example.com>"
```

Following is what i am trying to do

```
  class User {
  // Properties
  public $setFirstName;
  public $setLastName;
  public $setEmail;

// Methods

function setFirstName($setFirstName) {
$this->setFirstName = $setFirstName;
}

   function setLastName($setLastName) {
$this->setLastName = $setLastName;
   }

   function setEmail($setEmail) {
     $this->setEmail = $setEmail;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain multiple method calls like this:

```
$user->setFirstName('John')->setLastName('Doe')...
```

Then you simply need to have each of your setter methods return the special self-referencing object variable `$this`:

```
function setFirstName($setFirstName) {
    $this->setFirstName = $setFirstName;
    return $this;
}
```

If you want `echo $user;` to display something meaningful, you can implement the `__toString` magic method. Have it `return` whatever string you want to display:

```
function __toString() {
    return sprintf('%s %s <%s>', $this->setFirstName, $this->setLastName, $this->setEmail);
}
```

Comment: thanks alex. with me the problem was that i was not know the name of the this process now find the name and its method changing. Thanks again